# File IO and the buffer

Tags: assembly, file-io, 68000

I want to read numbers from a file, but when I do is everything read from the file put into the buffer? Or only 1 number? File would contain `5 6 7 10 9`

This would be what I'm using to read from the file: (EASy68K program)

```
    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

    lea     filename,a1
    move #52,d0
    trap #15

    lea     buffer,a1
    move    #datasize,d2    # bytes to read
    move    #53,d0          read from file
    trap    #15

    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

filename    dc.b    'test1.txt',0

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should read `datasize` bytes into memory starting at `buffer`. How many numbers that loads will depend on how large the numbers are and how big `datasize` is. If `datasize` is 1, then it will only load one number. If `datasize` is 3, then it will load `5 6`.

Assuming I'm reading the code correctly ... it's been a few years. . .

Comment: Does it work so that If i read 1 datasize, then loop back and read the next it will read 6?

Comment: It reads 1 character at a time. So the first time through it would read `5`. The second time, it would read the space. Third time it would read `6`.